# Remote Connection to SQL Server 2012 Standard Edition port 1433

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, remote-connection

I have a Windows Server 2008 R2 running SQL Server 2012 Standard Edition and:

- Allow remote connection to this server (in SQL Server Management Studio)
- TCP/IP Enable and configured IPserver and 1433 port (on SQL Server Network Condiguration -> Protocol for...)
- Named Pipes Enable (on SQL Server Network Condiguration -> Protocol for...)
- Shared Memory Enable (on SQL Server Network Condiguration -> Protocol for...)
- Firewall Off

When I run `telnet localhost 1433` on the server - connect perfect. But if I run `telnet IPSserver 1433` or `telnet DomainNameServer 1433` - not connect

Something else `netstat -a` display:

```
0.0.0.0:1433   NameServer:0  LISTENING
[::]:1433      NameServer:0  LISTENING
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have the Firewall turned on, so you have to create an exception to TCP/1433.

Be aware that if you have multiple instances you must also create an exception for UDP/1434 and check on which port the multiple instances are binding.